# React State not updating as expected when using in array index

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update a react state, referenced as an array position index.
So, I want the state to be updated in a way that the position should be updated back and forth.

Like the below,

**0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 .......**

Now, below is the code, I am using to update as expected above.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./02-LandStyle.scss";

export default function IntroLine() {
    const positions = ["0vh", "-6vh", "-12vh"];
    const [posNo, setposNo] = useState(0);
    let goReverese = false;

    useEffect(() => {
        const updatePos = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(posNo, goReverese);
            if (goReverese == false) {
                if (posNo == 2) {
                    goReverese = true;
                } else {
                    setposNo((t) => t + 1);
                }
            }

            if (goReverese == true) {
                if (posNo < 0) {
                    goReverese = false;
                } else {
                    setposNo((t) => t - 1);
                }
            }
        }, 2000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(updatePos);
        };
    });

    return (
        <div className="intro-text">
            <h2>Delivers </h2>
            <div className="inner-container">
                <div
                    className="inner-box"
                    // style={{ top: `${positions[posNo]}` }}
                >
                    <div className="slogan-item">
                        <h2>FOOD</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="slogan-item">
                        <h2>LOVE</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="slogan-item">
                        <h2>HAPPINESS</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But instead, it is behaving like the below.

**0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 .....**

This was found to be a simple bug, but I couldn't trace it somehow.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing posNo, the component rerenders and another interval gets called. I think it's better to use useRef. Also never compare a boolean like this : goReverese == true. just use goReverese instead.
Also never use useEffect without a dependency.
Try this. It will give you the result you want:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./02-LandStyle.scss";

export default function IntroLine() {
    const positions = ["0vh", "-6vh", "-12vh"];
    const posNo = useRef(0);
    let goReverese = false;

    useEffect(() => {
       const updatePos = setInterval(() => {
          console.log(posNo.current, goReverese);
          if (goReverese) {
               if (posNo.current === 1) {
                  goReverese = false;
               }
               posNo.current -= 1;
          } else {
             if (posNo.current === 1) {
                goReverese = true;
             }
             posNo.current += 1;
          }
     }, 2000);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(updatePos);
     };
   }, []);

    return (
        <div className="intro-text">
            <h2>Delivers </h2>
            <div className="inner-container">
                <div
                    className="inner-box"
                    // style={{ top: `${positions[posNo]}` }}
                >
                    <div className="slogan-item">
                    <h2>FOOD</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="slogan-item">
                    <h2>LOVE</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="slogan-item">
                    <h2>HAPPINESS</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   );
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ela. This is what I exactly needed. Seems like using the state to do this is a bad idea. After referening some docs, I understood why you used Ref. ❤️

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function IntroLine() {
  const positions = ["0vh", "-6vh", "-12vh"];
  const [posNo, setposNo] = useState(0);
  let goReverese = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatePos = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(posNo, goReverese);
      if (goReverese.current === false) {
        if (posNo === 2) {
          goReverese.current = true;
        } else {
          setposNo((t) => t + 1);
        }
      }

      if (goReverese.current === true) {
        if (posNo <= 0) {
          goReverese.current = false;
        } else {
          setposNo((t) => t - 1);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(updatePos);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="intro-text">
      <h2>Delivers </h2>
      <div className="inner-container">
        <div
          className="inner-box"
          // style={{ top: `${positions[posNo]}` }}
        >
          <div className="slogan-item">
            <h2>FOOD</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="slogan-item">
            <h2>LOVE</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="slogan-item">
            <h2>HAPPINESS</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace (posNo < 0) with (posNo <= 0). Hope it works.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I am getting the positions as 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2.... so on

Answer (score 0):

You should add the 2nd paramter in useEffect, otherewise, useEffect will execute in each render loop as the state changed inside it.
try this

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const updatePos = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(posNo, goReverese);
            if (goReverese == false) {
                if (posNo == 2) {
                    goReverese = true;
                } else {
                    setposNo((t) => t + 1);
                }
            }

            if (goReverese == true) {
                if (posNo < 0) {
                    goReverese = false;
                } else {
                    setposNo((t) => t - 1);
                }
            }
        }, 2000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(updatePos);
        };
    },[]); <--- add the dependencies paramter. empty array means only execute once
```

checkout the reference doc [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#parameters)

Comment: Thank you so much @kent. Your point about adding the dependency array is correct..  But this still did not move the position as expected. It moves as  0- > 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 .... .